# Sharing Files in Android with some partners using Dropbox

Tags: android, dropbox-api, file-sharing, data-sharing, android-sharing

this is the first time I'm taking a look at the Dropbox API so I'm afraid I kinda don't understand much.

My purpose is to develop an App in which I place some files into a directory so as to be automatically uploaded to the server and synced in another device whose owner I'm sharing them with, so different accounts are being used of course.

In the end, it has to be something similar to Dropbox app itself: you are able to create a file, upload it and share it with some friends.

Any idea if this is possible, what to begin with, is it possible to use for this goal any folder i want or it has to be one particularly chosen by Dropbox...?

Comment: Cross-linking with the Dropbox API forum: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=122199.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking for a way to *programmatically* share a folder with another user, the API doesn't currently support that. To do what you're doing, you would need to manually (with the Dropbox app or via dropbox.com) share a folder with the other user. From then on, you could use the Dropbox API to read from and write to that shared folder. (And the same would work from the other account, since the folder would be visible to both of you.)

Comment: And is there any other way to do it maybe with Google Drive or another server?

I want to have an App in which I open a file, I do some stuff with it, I place it in another different directory and at the end this "modified file" is uploaded and shared with some partners of mine, but all of it done from my App, no matter what server is used

Comment: These are computers. You can certainly program whatever you want. :-)

Comment: I know, but sometimes the way to do so it's not easily clear in beguinning for oneself :)

Comment: Do you know if there's another server whose API enables to do what I'm looking for?